# Fill out custom field with used coupon code WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, field, segment, coupon

Right now I'm working with a mailchimp plugin that needs a custom field for validating/segmenting.

For this segment I want to check what kind of coupon is used. So I scavenged the following code that should fill my custom field with the used coupons:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 
'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
if ( empty( $_POST['my_field_name'] ) ) {
    $coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_field_name', $coupons);
}
}
```

Sadly this will only crash my site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add the PHP error? any log?

Comment: I cannot, however I figured something out.
changing: `$coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();`
To: `$coupons = $order_id->get_used_coupons();`
keeps it from crashing but will still not fill out my field.

This is probably due the fact that $order was never defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your code:

- You're not validating if the field has any information, so you need
  to check if `$_POST` has the my_field_name key
- You need to load the `$order` variable in order to get the used coupons.
- What happens when there's a my_field_value? Do you store it?

Here's the modified code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 
'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id, $posted ) {
  if ( isset($_POST['my_field_name']) && empty( $_POST['my_field_name'])) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'my_field_name', $coupons);
  }

}
```

Comment: Okay your code kinda works, however it wil return 'array' as coupon field and the value is never displayed in the actual field on the front-end. Which is where I think i need it to be able to let my plugin check if the custom field contains certain coupon codes.

Comment: by replacing `$coupons = $order->get_used_coupons();` with `foreach( $order->get_used_coupons() as $coupon) {
          $coupons .= $coupon.'\n';
                }` I no longer get 'array' in my field but the actual coupon. So that part is solved..

Comment: Yes, you need to validate that as well. Also remember that you can store arrays in the post meta

Comment: It's better to do explode($order->get_used_coupons(),'\n') that the foreach

Comment: Thank you! The remaining problems I have, have nothing to do with the code but with the plugin it seems. Problem solved.